# Cannot see Decimal Value of a Cell in DataGridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I cannot Display the value of "Price" cell on my gridview, here's my code:

```
DataColumn idCol2 = new DataColumn();
        idCol2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        idCol2.ColumnName = "Id";
        table.Columns.Add(idCol2);

        DataColumn SKUCol2 = new DataColumn();
        SKUCol2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        SKUCol2.ColumnName = "SKU";
        table.Columns.Add(SKUCol2);

        DataColumn ProdNameCol2 = new DataColumn();
        ProdNameCol2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        ProdNameCol2.ColumnName = "Product Name";
        table.Columns.Add(ProdNameCol2);

        DataColumn DescCol2 = new DataColumn();
        DescCol2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        DescCol2.ColumnName = "Product Description";
        table.Columns.Add(DescCol2);

        DataColumn PriceCol2 = new DataColumn();
        PriceCol2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        PriceCol2.ColumnName = "Price";
        table.Columns.Add(PriceCol2);

        DataColumn[] keys2 = new DataColumn[5];
        keys2[0] = idCol2;
        table.PrimaryKey = keys2;

        LivePOS livepos = new LivePOS(clientId, clientSecret);
        _products = livepos.GetProducts(apiKey, token);

        foreach (var p in _products)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(p.Id, p.Sku, p.Name, p.Description , p.SellingPrice);
        }

        table.DefaultView.Sort = "Id ASC";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N4";

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            row.Cells[0].ReadOnly = false; //id

            row.Cells[1].ReadOnly = true; //sku
            row.Cells[2].ReadOnly = true; //name
            row.Cells[3].ReadOnly = true; //description
        }
```

Please help me :)Is there something wrong in this code? I created new instance of the datatable named "table" on my Form_Load event. All cell values are displaying correctly aside from this "Price" column.

Comment: what is the Type you are using for Price in DB and give us the sample value from _products ...

Comment: `DECIMAL(19,4) will require 9 storage bytes
MONEY will require 8 storage bytes` please verify as well as clarify what the DataType of Price is defined in the Database

Comment: Can you give example of what the issue is with the display like the expected number and the displayed one ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Price Column should have Datatype of Double than Decimal.Take a look at this link
[Decimal Vs Double](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/)

hope that helps

Comment: I think you have this in the reverse order.. it's better to set the data type for Currency as Decimal

Comment: Price is decimal on my Products class

Comment: But when I tried to bind the gridview using the list _products, it displays the price